# How can I add a counter to this foreach loop?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, counter

How can I add a counter to this code?

```
foreach(DataSet1.Save_PropertyRow r in DT)
{
    var testProperty = CreateTestAOProperty(r.ADDRESS, r.Adjustments...);
    var savePropertyResult = _Client.SaveProperty(credentials, testProperty);
Console.WriteLine("Save Property result: \"{0}\" with message \"{1}\"", savePropertyResult.Status, savePropertyResult.Message);

LogMessageToFile(CaseID, "Property Results Saved to log");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and why not using a for loop when you need an index?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Show us what you have tried and what specific issues you are getting.

Comment: Why not a integer variable defined outside the loop(let it be `i`) and a `i++` inside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an integer outside of the loop, and increment it inside of your loop.

```
int count = 0;
foreach(value in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Current count: {0}", count);
    //Do your thing.
    count++;
}
```

**OR**

Use a for loop instead of foreach, which has a count for you:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    var item = array[i];
    Console.WriteLine("Current count: {0}", i + 1);
    //Do your thing.
}
```

Comment: Thank you ThePerplexedOne much appreciated